# Disable Paste Data Image on Tinymce Moodle

Tags: image, tinymce, moodle, text-editor

Where can I put this code to disable paste data image? I tried put the code on additional html moodle, but it's not working

```
tinyMCE.init({
 selector: 'textarea',  // change this value according to your HTML
 toolbar: 'paste',
 paste_data_images: false
});
```

Please give me the solution, thank you before

[This is I have tried](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zpgjh.png)